# Time averaged product of electromagnetic waves that go in two different directions

Tags: electromagnetism

I have to use this equation (the tildes represent imaginary numbers)

$$\langle fg\rangle={1\over 2}Re({\tilde f^*}\tilde g)$$

to find the time averaged power dissipated in currents for an electromagnetic wave in a conductor. The wave equations I have are

$${\mathbf E}(z,t)= Re\big[\tilde {\mathbf E}(z,t)\big]$$ and
$${\mathbf B}(z,t)= Re\big[\tilde {\mathbf B}(z,t)\big],$$

where $\tilde {\mathbf E}(z,t)=E_0 \hat x e^{i(\tilde kz-\omega t)}$ and $\tilde {\mathbf B}(z,t)={{\tilde k}\over \omega}E_0\hat ye^{i(\tilde k t-\omega z)}$.

I'm not sure how it would even be possible for me to multiply the two wave equations together because the are in different directions, and the time averaged equation doesn't say anything about a dot or cross product. I'm also not sure how I choose a function to take the place of $\tilde f$ and $\tilde g$.

How is it possible to multiply these two functions and how do I choose which function takes the place of $\tilde f$ and $\tilde g$?